# Uno Platform: Error building UWP project when .Net Native toolchain is enabled

Tags: uwp, uno-platform

I'm trying to create a release build for my UWP project with .net native toolchain enabled and I get the following error

```
1>  Process execution statistics (all times in milliseconds) (TaskId:226)
1>  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- (TaskId:226)
1>  launch  |  start   |   stop   |   end    | duration | lifetime | [slot] name (TaskId:226)
1>  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- (TaskId:226)
1>         0 |        0 |      844 |      875 |      844 |      875 | [0] Gatekeeper (TaskId:226)
1>  Number of commands:      1 (TaskId:226)
1>  Total system time:       875 ms (TaskId:226)
1>  System time per command: 875 ms (TaskId:226)
1>  Total duration:          844 ms (TaskId:226)
1>  Total lifetime:          875 ms (TaskId:226)
1>  Requested DOP:           12 (TaskId:226)
1>  Duration DOP:            1.0 (TaskId:226)
1>  Lifetime DOP:            1.0 (TaskId:226)
1>  Done executing task "Gatekeeper". (TaskId:226)
1>  Done building target "RunGatekeeper" in file "Preparation". (TaskId:226)
1>   (TaskId:226)
1>  Done building target "CreateToolchainGeneratedAssembly" in file "Preparation". (TaskId:226)
1>   (TaskId:226)
1>  Task "PreMergeAssemblyClosure" (TaskId:226)
1>  Done executing task "PreMergeAssemblyClosure". (TaskId:226)
1>  Done building target "ConstructPreMergeAssemblyClosure" in file "Preparation". (TaskId:226)
1>   (TaskId:226)
1>  Task "McgReferenceResolveFilePath" (TaskId:226)
1>  Done executing task "McgReferenceResolveFilePath". (TaskId:226)
1>  Done building target "PreResolveTransforms" in file "Preparation". (TaskId:226)
1>   (TaskId:226)
1>  Task "ResolveToolchainRequiredAssemblyRoots" (TaskId:226)
1>  Done executing task "ResolveToolchainRequiredAssemblyRoots". (TaskId:226)
1>  Task "ILTransformAssemblyClosure" (TaskId:226)
1>  Done executing task "ILTransformAssemblyClosure". (TaskId:226)
1>  Task "ResolveToolchainRequiredAssemblyRoots" (TaskId:226)
1>  Done executing task "ResolveToolchainRequiredAssemblyRoots". (TaskId:226)
1>  Task "ReducedCopyAssemblyClosure" (TaskId:226)
1>  Done executing task "ReducedCopyAssemblyClosure". (TaskId:226)
1>  Done building target "ConstructILTransformAssemblyClosure" in file "Preparation". (TaskId:226)
1>  Done building project "Preparation". (TaskId:226)
1>   (TaskId:226)
1>   (TaskId:226)
1>  Processing application code (TaskId:226)
1>  Task "RunILTransforms" (TaskId:226)
1>  Running 'DumpNativeResources' transform, heap at 31 MB. (TaskId:226)
1>  Running 'Analysis' transform, heap at 48 MB. (TaskId:226)
1>  Loading 272 modules... (TaskId:226)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.2.12-rel-31116-00\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets(809,5): error : Internal compiler error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
1>  Done executing task "RunILTransforms" -- FAILED. (TaskId:226)
1>  Done building target "RunILTransforms" in file "ILTransforms" -- FAILED. (TaskId:226)
1>  Done building project "ILTransforms" -- FAILED. (TaskId:226)
1>  Compilation failed (TaskId:226)
1>   (TaskId:226)
1>  The command exited with code 1201. (TaskId:226)
1>  Output Property: _IlcExitCode=1201 (TaskId:226)
1>Done executing task "LoggerBasedExecTask" -- FAILED. (TaskId:226)
1>Done building target "BuildNativePackage" in project "Chorus.Note.UWP.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:193)
```

After attempting to submit our app to the windows store, the app was rejected and they recommended that we build the project with .NET Native Toolchain enabled. Now I can't get it to build.